# __typeof -identifier not found

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

For some reason I keep getting

```
error C3861: '__typeof': identifier not found
```

when I compile my program!

I'm including the following libraries:

```
<iostream>
<stdlib>
<stdio>
```

Any ideas?

thanks

Edit:

More example

```
User.h
class User{}

main.cpp
void f(User* p)
{
.
.
.
__typeof(p) ...
.
.
.
.
}
```

Comment: __typeof() is a managed code extension and exists only if compiling for the CLR in Visual Studio 2005 (the old managed syntax extensions). Are you compiling to native code? Which version of Visual C++ are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x2xw8750%28VS.71%29.aspx

`__typeof` only exists for /clr:oldSyntax. Are you trying to use Managed extensions to C++ or are you expecting `__typeof` to work like C++0x's `decltype`? If so, if you are using VS 2010 you can use `decltype`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the function `__typeof()` doesn't exist? Do you mean `typeof()`?

[How to typeof in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540086/how-to-typeof-in-c)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding:

```
#using <mscorlib.dll>
using namespace System;
```

to the top of your C file and compile with `/clr /LD`.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712813%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)