# Difference between choosing a subclass via a template parameter or instantiating a member variable

Tags: c++

Say I have a class that can use different types of distance functions (Euclidean distance, etc) to do some comparisons. I have implemented these functions as subclasses of a class Distance:

```
class Distance;
class EuclideanDistance : public Distance;
class OtherDistance : public Distance;
```

It seems that to choose which type of distance to use, I could do:

```
template <typename TDistance>
class MyClass;
```

and instantiate it with:

```
MyClass<EuclideanDistance> instance;
```

or accomplish the same thing with:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
 Distance* myDistanceFunction;
}
```

and instantiating it with

```
MyClass instance;
instance.myDistanceFunction = new EuclideanDistance;
```

are there any advantages of one method over the other?

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Association (i.e. the solution without templates) is preferable since it offers you more flexibility, allows you to change distance implementation at runtime, generates cleaner error messages and cleaner object files (fewer symbols).

Also, classes generated from the template parametrized with different types (distance implementations) will be considered different types and will not be interchangeable: `MyClass<EuclideanDistance>` is a different type than `MyClass<MinkowskiDistance>`. This will force you to make all functions that operate on `MyClass` templates as well and will ultimately lead to greater complexity with no added benefits.

Templates should be used when you need to relax type-safety of the language, for example when you are writing a class which should operate on a number of **unrelated** types (not derived from a common base class/interface) which nonetheless behave in a similar manner (e.g. all have a `kwak()` member function). This is called [*duck-typing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing): types are formally unrelated but all exhibit similar properties.

In case you're prevented from ensuring that all distance implementations derive from a common base class/interface, you may need to use templates. Otherwise, prefer simple and flexible association.

Answer (score 4):

Well, aside from the compile time vs run time issue, the biggest difference has kind of been disallowed by your pre-existing code.  Using a template would have allowed you to use any types that supported a common operation (i.e. getDistance) without them having to be from the same heirarchy.  This would have meant that Euclidean distance and your other class could have been completely different, yet still useable in the template as long as they supported the subset of members the template made use of.

Comment: I see - so I would just have EuclideanDistance and OtherDistance be separate classes, not derived from any parent Distance class.

Comment: It would be perfectly possible :) Templates allow generic programming, treating things that have the same implicit interface (the things required by the template) as the same.  It's the same concept as how the STL often lets you pass in a functor (a function object) or an actual function - the template using the passed in function or functor doesn't care which one it is, it just cares that the passed in parameter is callable with the () syntax.  So, templates are alot more flexible than inheritance heirarchies (but there are definitely pros and cons to both).

Answer (score 2):

The former fixes the distance metric for the class at compile-time, while the second does it at run-time. The former is likely more efficient because it allows the compiler to optimize parts of it away, while the second can be more flexible.

Comment: In the second method - is there a way to create a second object of the same type as the first?

Comment: @DavidDoria: what kind of object do you mean? A `MyClass`, a `EuclideanDistance`?

Comment: Another object of the same type as myDistanceFunction inside of MyClass.

Comment: @DavidDoria: If you make a `typename TDistance` inside a `MyClass<EuclideanDistance>`, then it will become a `EuclideanDistance`.

Comment: Sure, but what about in the other case - the non-templated class. Could you use the typeof() function or something like that to create a second instance of a distance function of the same type as the "main" distance function object in the class?

Comment: @DavidDoria: see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540086/how-to-typeof-in-c).

Answer (score 1):

Public inheritance means IS-A.  Is a EuclideanDisatance interoperable with a "LorentzDistance" or "QuaternionDistance" (or whatever) in any meaningful way?  Are they both "distances" in the sense that some code somewhere would be happy to use either one in a non-trivial way (that is, something other than printing the value, etc...)?  My guess is no, it's not.

So you want generics, not inheritance.  Templates are a simpler promise: two things "look like" each other syntactically.