# how to get typeof variable in C++

Tags: c++, typeof

I need to know a built-in function or anyway to get the type of a variable in C++

I want to check the type of the variable in a generic method.

for INSTANCE

```
template<class Numbers> bool Matrix(Numbers matrix[] ,int matrixsize)
{
 if (/* type of matrix is int */)
   return false;
 else
   return true;
}
```

Comment: Could you post some (pseudo) code of how you'd want to use that exactly?

Comment: Could you please post relevant code snippet and point out where is the problem?

Comment: template<class Numbers> bool Matrix(Numbers matrix[] ,int matrixsize)
{
if type of matrix is int return false;
else return true;
} 
for INSTANCE

Comment: You have do little bit of work for this. This post might help [type cast][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1540086/how-to-typeof-in-c

Comment: If you want to do that, you are almost certainly on the wrong track. You need to post (in the question!) exactly what you want to do and why you want to do it this way. I am sure there's a better way to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### New answer

For as far as my decryption skills go, the comments made the question slightly more clear. What you want is template specialization.

```
template<class Numbers>
bool Matrix(Numbers matrix[] ,int matrixsize) {
  return true;
}

template<>
bool Matrix(int matrix[] ,int matrixsize) {
  return false;
}
```

---

#### Old answer

If you want to do this at compile time, in C++11 you can use `decltype` to get the type of any expression:

```
int my_variable;
decltype(my_variable) other_variable; // has type int
```

I'm not aware of any way to do this (easily) in C++03.

---

If you want to get the type of an object at runtime (which can be useful when dealing with polymorphism, sometimes), you can use the `typeid()` operator and [`std::type_info`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info).

```
#include <type_info>
// ...

void foo(some_virtual_class& base) {
  const std::type_info& info = typeid(base);
  // Do something with the type info.
}
```

Comment: In C++03 there's Boost Typeof, which may be supported by various platform-specific extensions, but OP gives no clue whether he wants this or `typeid` or something else…

Comment: no that is not what i want to do . 
 i want to do something like this 
for INSTANCE

template<class Numbers> bool Matrix(Numbers matrix[] ,int matrixsize)
{
if type of matrix is int return false;
else return true;
}

Answer (score 4):

The better way to do what you stated in the comments is with template specialization:

```
template<class Numbers>
bool Matrix(Numbers matrix[] ,int matrixsize) {
  return true;
}

template<> // full specialziation on int
bool Matrix(int matrix[] ,int matrixsize) {
  return false;
}
```

This will branch at *compile time* which template to use: the first (general) one, or the second (specialized).  You can have more than one specialization as well if you need

If there are places where you want to branch based on *dynamic* type (e.g. whether a pointer to base class actually points to a base class of one of its derivatives), you should be able to use `dynamic_cast<>` in most cases:

```
class Base {
  public: virtual ~Base();
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public: void mySpecialMethod();
};
void f(Base* b) {
  Derived* d = dynamic_cast<Derived*> (b);
  if (d != NULL) {
    // *b's actual type is (derivative of) Derived
    d->mySpecialMethod();
  }
}
```

Note that the best way would be to do proper inheritance instead:

```
class Base {
  public:
    virtual Base();
    virtual void myMethod();
};
class Derived : public Base {
  public: void myMethod();
};
void f(Base* b) {
  b->myMethod();
}
```

if `*b`'s actual type is `Derived`, Derived::myMethod() is called; if `*b`'s actual type is `Base`, Base::myMethod() is called; etc.  If it makes no sense to call `myMethod` on a `Base` object (but does for all its derived classes), you can make it pure virtual by adding `=0` to its declation in `Base`.  Or just define an empty body (might not work well if it needs to return a value)

Answer (score 1):

In C++, manipulation of types falls under the umbrella term of "metaprogramming," and the function you describe would be a "metafunction."

The new Standard defines various metafunctions including one that strips array bounds and one that checks for type equivalence.

This expression evaluates to a constant `true`:

```
std::is_same< typename std::remove_extent< int[] >::type, int >::value
```

With C++11, you can use this with `#include <type_traits>`. With older compilers, you can probably access it through either `#include <tr1/type_traits>` or `#include <type_traits>`, and then use `std::tr1::is_same` and `std::tr1::remove_extent`.

If you want to encapsulate the expression rather than write it out each time (as it's rather ugly), it's simple to define your own metafunction:

```
template< typename T >
struct array_is_int {
    enum { value =
        std::is_same< typename std::remove_extent< int[] >::type,
                         int >::value
    };
};
```

If later you want to return `true` for `unsigned int` as well, just modify the expression:

```
template< typename T >
struct array_is_int {
    enum { value =
        std::is_same< typename std::remove_extent< int[] >::type,
                         int >::value
        || std::is_same< typename std::remove_extent< int[] >::type,
                         unsigned int >::value
    };
};
```

This is easier than dealing with specializations, which depend on the function overloading rules.